# Dynamic to static

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

My site is an e-commerce site. All URLs are dynamic, like "my_domain/a.php", "my_domain/a.php?id=1", "my_domain/b.php", "my_domain/b.php?id=3", etc.

I want static URLs like "my_domain/a.html","my_domain/b.html","my_domain/c.html", "my_domain/d.html", etc.

I am little weak in the .htaccess file. What do I add to my .htaccess file o achieve that result?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for an answer similar to this question for a while now.

For something like your example, you could do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /testpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I found this website this morning which helps to generate these re-write rules

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

it's output was:

```
The original URL:
http://mywebsite.com/testpage.php?id=1
The rewritten URL:
http://mywebsite.com/1
```